# Magento CSS not Loading in New Template

Tags: css, templates, magento

I have posted on the template creator's site, as well as Magento support, but no one has responded.

The CSS is not loading at all on the custom theme I have installed, which is supposedly compatible with the current version of Magento.

You can view the page here: shop.dearearth.net

This is a fresh installation of Magento and the theme, with a fresh database.

I have a feeling it should be a relatively quick fix.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Please post the names of the files that aren't loading (including the path from /skin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the links in your page referring to the

```
http://www.shop.dearearth.net/skin/frontend/base/
```

directory on your site returns 404. Make sure your css files are in fact in there. Also make sure your links aren't being broken by a .htaccess file.

Comment: thanks! you are right, they are pointing to the wrong location... looking to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your CSS is 777 rights by admin.
OR
Please copy the whole code from latest css and take it as a backup and create a new css file as same name and past the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check in admin back-end, System > Configuration > General/Design if your theme is right specified. Also check if after you installed the new theme, the files have the proper rights (normally, they must be accessible by the web server with Write permissions)
For more info please also take a look at [Magento Designers Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide) for understanding of how Magento read and split template information. Maybe you have put the CSS and images in a wrong directory :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.. sort of. The version of the template turned out to be quite outdated, and the incompatible with the current version of Magento, which handles things differently in terms of calling styles in the page.xml file.

Thanks for your inputs.